# Liferay Vaadin 7 Portlet: Init Method is not Called when Page is Refreshed

Tags: liferay, vaadin, portlet, liferay-6

In a Liferay portlet, a Vaadin 7 UI's `init` method is only called once, even when the page the portlet is on is refreshed in the browser with F5.

There is a solution for Vaadin 6 outlined here: https://www.liferay.com/de/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/12501036

But, for the current Vaadin version 7, this method doesn't work, as the class `PortletApplicationContext2` is no longer part of Vaadin.

How can I, in a Vaadin 7 Liferay portlet UI, react on the user refreshing the page with F5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PortletListener interface.

[Here](http://dev.vaadin.com/svn/doc/book-examples/branches/vaadin-7/src/com/vaadin/book/applications/PortletCustomModeExample.java) you can find example.

Comment: Hello Paul, thanks for your answer. The `handleResourceRequest` method gets called, indeed. But, it doesn't seem to be in the correct Vaadin context, as for example `Page.getCurrent` returns `null`

Comment: Could you please paste code example, who describes what is wrong?

Comment: Hello Paul, I've solved my original problem in another way. Seems that I have to initialize all Vaadin components in the `init()` method. Regards, Samuel